# how node js connect with mongodb using tcp?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tcp

How the tcp connection is established and closed during the database call?

The below code is  to get lists of databases in mongodb using mongoclient in nodejs

```
async function main(){

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
 

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
 
    try {
       
        await client.connect();
 
        await  listDatabases(client);

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

1.Does the  "await client.connect()" establish a tcp connection with mongoDb?

2.Does the  "await client.close()"close a tcp connection with mongoDb?

3.How does the mongodb and nodejs communicate using tcp ?

Answer (score 0):

node-mongodb-native's [`.connect()`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/mongo_client.ts#L432-L484) and [`.close()`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/mongo_client.ts#L486-L562) manage a [`Topology`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1eea4f0f5821bb44c86f653d5a3a6c022a5cf55b/src/sdam/topology.ts#L191) of [`Server`s](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1eea4f0f5821bb44c86f653d5a3a6c022a5cf55b/src/sdam/server.ts#L116) that have [`Monitor`ed](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1eea4f0f5821bb44c86f653d5a3a6c022a5cf55b/src/sdam/monitor.ts#L71) [`Connection`s](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1eea4f0f5821bb44c86f653d5a3a6c022a5cf55b/src/cmap/connection.ts#L165) communicating via a [`MessageStream`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1eea4f0f5821bb44c86f653d5a3a6c022a5cf55b/src/cmap/message_stream.ts#L50)